# Split Url with / and replace data using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to split the url and replace with object data using javascript.
I have url like these

```
www.xyz.com/en/transfer-services/details
www.xyz.com/en/about-info,
www.xyz.com/en/contact,
www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-mal-to-sin/details

var obj1={
  "transfer-services": "xi-hou-zhi-n",
  "about-info": "zhi-zhu",
  "contact": "zhi-phi",
  "all-services-from": "hui-zhi-phi-tho",
  "to": "zhi"
}
```

I have a button and on click should change the url is www.xyz.com/en/xi-hou-zhi-n/details,change to www.xyz.com/en/transfer-services/details and vice-versa.

when the button is clicked, if the url is full of english language then use obj1 keys else obj1 values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reduce`.

```js
const urls = [
    "www.xyz.com/en/transfer-services/details",
    "www.xyz.com/en/about-info",
    "www.xyz.com/some/zhi-phi",
    "www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-mal-to-sin/details"
];

var obj1={
  "transfer-services": "xi-hou-zhi-n",
  "about-info": "zhi-zhu",
  "contact": "zhi-phi",
  "all-services-from": "hui-zhi-phi-tho",
  "to": "zhi",
    "to": "zhi",
    "sin": "stin",
    "mal": "zmal"
};

const output = urls.reduce((accu, url) => {
    let [base, lang, segment, ...rest] = url.split('/');

    if(lang == 'en' && obj1.hasOwnProperty(segment)) {
        segment =  obj1[segment] ;
    } else {
        Object.entries(obj1).forEach(([key, val]) => {
            if(val == segment) { segment = key } ;
        });
    }

    accu.push([base,lang, segment, ...rest].join('/'));
    return accu;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

---Edit---

```js
var obj1={
    "transfer-services": "xi-hou-zhi-n",
    "about-info": "zhi-zhu",
    "contact": "zhi-phi",
    "all-services-from": "hui-zhi-phi-tho",
    "to": "zhi",
    "sin": "stin",
    "mal": "zmal"
};

function transformURL(url) {
    let [base, lang, segment, ...rest] = url.split('/');
    if(lang == 'en' && obj1.hasOwnProperty(segment)) {
        segment = obj1[segment];
    } else {
        Object.entries(obj1).forEach(([key, val]) => {
            if(val == segment) {segment = key};
        });
    }

    return [base, lang, segment, ...rest].join('/');
}
console.log(transformURL('www.xyz.com/en/transfer-services/details'));
```

Comment: thanks a lot but does not for url `www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-mal-to-sin/details`

Comment: is it possible to do without array , since each time will have handle single url as a string

Comment: @miyavv - Yes, you can have a separate function and pass individual url to the function. See Edit. For url `www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-mal-to-sin/details`, the obj1 do not have property `all-services-from-mal-to-sin`. So, it remain unchanged.

Comment: thanks but need to change url for sin and mal as well, current code not working can you please help. thanks `www.xyz.com/en/all-services-from-mal-to-sin/details` to `www.xyz.com/en/hui-zhi-phi-tho-zmal-zhi-stin` and vice-versa